# How to decide the HTTP verb for RAML (REST API) when doing a WSDL to RAML Migration?

Tags: java, rest, http, wsdl, raml

I am trying to create a WSDL to RAML converter. During the initial analysis I stumbled upon a question on deciding what should be the **HTTP verb (PUT, POST, GET,DELETE)** to be used for my REST api representation within RAML for each WSDL operation.

I can't propose a pattern of identifying the HTTP verb based on WSDL operation as there is no specific standard\guidelines on naming convention for WSDL operation.

Could anyone suggest an option by which i can map a WSDL operation to an HTTP verb?

Regards
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Good old Wikipedia has the following table in their [REST article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Example):

[image]

This can get you started.

Further readings:

- http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction
- https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_nouns_are_good_verbs_are_bad

Comment: Thanks David for your response but what I am looking is for any option or pattern by which i could relate\map an WSDL operation with a REST HTTP verb.

Comment: Thanks David for your response but what I am looking is for any option or pattern by which i could relate\map an WSDL operation with a REST HTTP verb. eg WSDL Operation is given with a name requestEmployee details now i can assume that it can be GET verb in HTTP but my converter program doesn't have that intelligence to understand the vocabulary request = GET. So I am looking for any other pattern by which I could make my converter program to understand and apply the right HTTP verb for right WSDL operation.

Comment: I don't see how you could do that without lexical analysis to distinguish CRUD verbs from the SOAP operations. Even a simple read in a doc/literal SOAP service is represented by an XML entity so you can't tell it apart from creates/updates, as they too take XML entities as input args.

Comment: Thanks David , that's exactly the point where I am standing now. Totally agree with you that an lexical analysis might be required . I was trying to find out any other options or even anyone has achieved it by any other means.